# How to create a Testing and QA network

Tags: networking, routing, dhcp

I am looking to create two new networks inside my private network. The two networks are QA and Dev. I would like to have the QA and Dev network separated (I am thinking different subdomains) that are accessible via the internal network.

Here are my current thoughts:

- Internal Network (Where all people would be connected) - 192.168.1.x

  - Netmask: 255.255.255.0
  - Broadcast: 192.168.1.255
  - DNS: From the ISP
- QA Network (where QA devices would be connected) - 192.168.2.x

  - Netmask: 255.255.255.0
  - Broadcast: 192.168.2.255
  - DNS: 192.168.1.1
- Dev Network (Where Dev devices would be connected) - 192.168.3.x

  - Netmask: 255.255.255.0
  - Broadcast: 192.168.1.255
  - DNS: 192.168.1.1

I am also need to find hardware to to this. So I am thinking a switch, where devices connected to QA/Dev pot get a correct DHCP address.

So I want to be 192.168.1.12 be able to connect to both 192.168.2.123 and 192.168.3.42 using my existing connection to 192.168.1.1.

What are some way's to do this?

Comment: This is a very odd question - my impression is you've done the network architecture (and done a decent job of it), but you're not sure how to take what you've drawn on paper and turn it into physical reality using switches, routers, firewalls, and cables.  I'm not sure Server Fault can help you with that part - your knowledge gap is on the opposite side of what we usually see...

Comment: @voretaq7 Do you have any recommendations for literature for me to read to I can get up to speed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using separate VLAN's wouldn't be a bad idea either.

Also switches need to be level 3 switches if you want them to do DHCP.

Also if you want segragation you shouldn't be routing between your networks of testing/QA and production.

Answer (score 2):

Most important part, is that you need a switch that will support 801.q vlan tagging. I would suggest the following,

Have a small linux box as a router, (enabling ip_forwarding=1) Then install/enable vlan on the network interface. There are many how-tos available via google. The linux box/router can also work as a firewall, blocking traffic, etc.